# Recursive call prolog and passing list

Tags: prolog

```
member_state(S, S|_).
member_state(X, _|T) :- member_state(X,T).

step1 :- step2(state(l,l,l,l)).
step2(X) :- step3(X|state(l,l,l,r)).
step3(X) :- step4(X|state(l,l,r,l)).
step4(X) :- member_state(state(l,l,l,l), X).
```

I am trying to create a list on each call, and then at the end check if the inserted state is in the created list by calling step1. prolog gives me a false result here. Can anyone point to the problem please? I need to get yes. Thank you. ( this is just a test - not the actual code )

Answer (score 0):

```
member_state(S, [S|_]).
member_state(X, [_|T]) :- member_state(X,T).

step1 :- step2([state(l,l,l,l)]).
step2(X) :- step3([state(l,l,l,r)|X]).
step3(X) :- step4([state(l,l,r,l)|X]).
step4(X) :- member_state(state(l,l,l,l), X).
```